# Keep the content of a text with specific same columns in command line

Tags: command-line, sed, comm

Basically I tried to operate files in command line like this:

```
File1:
,1,this is some content,
,2,another content,
,3,blablabla,
,4,xxxxxxxx,
,5,yyyyyyyy,
,6,zzzzzzzzzz,
... ...



File2:
1
3
4 
5
```

Now I want to keep the content of file1 with the same column numbers in file2, so the output should be:

```
,1,this is some content,
,3,blablabla,
,4,xxxxxxxx,
,5,yyyyyyyy,
```

I used `comm -3 file1 file2` but it doesn't work. Then I tried sed but also didn't work. Is there any other handy tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will work on the example as given - it won't work if numbers appear in your string after the comma:

```
grep -F -f File2 File1
```

An alternative would be

```
join -t, -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 File1 File2
```

Here is how that works:

```
-t,                 considers the `,` as terminator
-1 2                look at the second column in file 1
-2 1                look at the first column in file 2
-o 1.1, 1.2, 1.3    output the first, second, third column of file 1
```

This still has the drawback that if there are multiple commas in the text that follows, it terminates after the first comma ("field 3" is the last one output).

Fixing that issue requires the use of `xargs`:

```
join -t, -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1, 1.2 File1 File2 | xargs -Ixx grep xx File1
```

**Explanation:**

`-Ixx` : replace the string `xx` in the command that follows with each of the output lines from the preceding command; the execute that command for each line. This means we will find the lines that match the first `,number,` which should make us insensitive to anything else.

Comment: ye this works, thank you! But is there an alternative one which won't be influenced by numbers' issue?

Comment: Aha cool! I understand now! This is more stable than grep -F -f... one. Thank you very much!